# Using Collections.frequency() for bigger than expression

Tags: java, filter, collections, frequency

I want to use the **Collection.frequency()** function as demonstrated below

`Collections.frequency(list, obj >= 2);`

The list here is **Long**

The goal is to find the frequency of the elements that are bigger or equal to 2

also tried the code below

`list.stream().filter(obj -> obj >= 2).count() >= 2`

anything else I can do?

full code

```
Map < E, Long > map =
                this.objs.stream().collect
                        (Collectors.groupingBy(Obj :: getE,Collectors.counting()));
        
return Collections.frequency(map.values(), (long) >= 2 ) >= 1
                && Collections.frequency(map.values(), (long) >= 3 ) >= 1;
```

v.s.

```
Map < E, Long > map =
                this.objs.stream().collect
                        (Collectors.groupingBy(Obj :: getE,Collectors.counting()));

List <Integer> list =
                map.values().stream().map(Long :: intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());

return list.stream().filter(count-> count >= 2).count() >= 1
                && list.stream().filter(count-> count >= 3).count() >= 1;
```

The problem is when using the filter with list it will always count the same element

Comment: Try `filter(obj -> obj.longValue() >= 2)`

Comment: Actually ... do you really mean list is `List<Long>` ... ?

Comment: Works for me: https://ideone.com/a07IRN. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Yeah the Collectors.counting() returns <Long>

Comment: was mixing a similar problem earlier(compareTo for Long)

Comment: So what is the question? You have a working solution using the Stream API and want to use the inappropriate `frequency` method for no good reason? And why do you test for `>=2` *and* `>=3`? The latter implies the former, so when you combine the results with `&&`, there is no reason to test for `>=2` at all. In short, you can simply use `return this.objs.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy( Obj::getE, Collectors.counting())) .values().stream().anyMatch(count -> count >= 3);`